# What files must be writable for a password change on a RHEL6 read-only file system?

Tags: read-only, rhel-6, passwd

I have a RedHat 6 system that is intentionally configured to be read-only file system. We use `/etc/rwtab` to allow certain files to be writable (log files and such). `/etc/sysconfig/readonly-root` is used to define the persistent storage of files.

While this is working well, the problem it created is when the users password expires they get "*passwd: Authentication token manipulation error*" because it can't write the password change.

The workaround has been to put the box temporarily in read-write mode, change the password, reboot into read-only.

I thought adding the `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/shadow-` to the `/etc/rwtab` list would allow for passwd changes but it does not. Should I be adding other files? What all takes place when the passwd command is successfully used to change a password?

Comment: I'd say that /etc/passwd should be writable as well

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it into r/w mode, and then using inotifywatch while you are changing a passwd.  That will tell you which files are being altered.